# Can't do string concat

Tags: python, string, concatenation

```
import random

possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
i = 0 
token = ''
while i<10:
    temp = random.choice(possible)
    print temp
    token = token + temp
    i=i+1

print temp
```

But it prints only the last randomly taken character.

print temp displays ten characters correctly though.

Comment: you probably wanted to `print token` on the last line

Comment: Bugs aside, there's a simpler way to do what you want: `''.join( random.choice(possible) for _ in range(10) )`

Comment: (and, in general, if you're manually incrementing a loop control variable in Python, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.)

Comment: @Wooble, why is it wrong incrementing a loop control variable in Python?

Comment: It's unpythonic; use `for i in xrange(how_many_times):` instead of a while loop.

Comment: @Wooble, posting complete code will be helpfull to understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you meant

```
print token
```

instead of

```
print temp
```

right at the very end?